# Please help get rid of the additional 0 I get in the result from the subtraction calculator

Tags: c

Please help me get rid of the garbage values and the additional 0, in the result I get from this large integer calculator in c. (Here the numbers are taken as strings since I have to work with very large numbers, which and integer data type cannot hold.  )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char v1[500],v2[500],result[500];
int i,j,k;
int a,b,c,x=0,y=0;
int p,q,r;
int elem=0, sum=0;

printf(" Please Enter 1st number: ");
gets(v1);
printf(" Please Enter 2nd number: ");
gets(v2);

a =strlen(v1);
b =strlen(v2);

for(i=a,j=b;i>=0||j>=0;i--,j--)
{
    if(i>=0)
    {
        x = v1[i]-48;
    }

    else
    {
        x = 0;
    }

    if(j>=0)
    {
        y = v2[j]-48;
    }

    else
    {
        y = 0;
    }

    sum=x-y;

    if(sum<0)
    {
        sum =sum+10;
        p = v1[i-1]- 48;
        q = p-1;
        v1[(i-1)]= q + 48;
    }

    sum= sum + 48;

    if(a>=b)
    {
        result[i]=sum;
    }

    if(b>a)
    {
        result[j]=sum;
    }

}


printf("\n\n    Subtraction Is: ");

for(k=0;result[k];k++)
{

    printf("%c",result[k]);
}



printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start from `i=a-1; j=b-1;` not `i=a,j=b`

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please help me get rid of the garbage values?

Comment: Since the difference of 2 numbers could be negative, suggest finding the greater of `a` and `b` first, then subtract the lesser from the smaller, finally applying the correct sign.

Answer (score 0):

Start from `i=a-1; j=b-1;` not `i=a,j=b` –  chux

Since the difference of 2 numbers could be negative, suggest finding the greater of `a` and `b` first, then subtract the lesser from the smaller, finally applying the correct sign. –  chux